# rails 4: AbstractController::DoubleRenderError with format

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rendering

I am creating a group record via Ajax request, and getting this error  ( in both cases , @group valid or invalid)

```
Started POST "/groups" for ::1 at 2015-10-28 17:47:08 +0100
Processing by GroupsController#create as JS

AbstractController::DoubleRenderError - Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please.....
```

I don't understand why , as redirect and render are not in the same blocks...

here is my controller

class GroupsController < ApplicationController
     respond_to :html, :js

```
def create
    @group = Group.new(company_id: current_user.company_id, name: params[:name] )
    if @group.save?
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to groups_path, notice: 'Group was successfully created.'}
        format.js
      end
    else 
      respond_to  do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to new_group_path }
        format.js
      end
    end
end
...
```

the error seems to happen when trying to render the create.js

```
 Rendered groups/create.js.erb (6.5ms)
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 48784ms (Views: 46.2ms |    ActiveRecord: 4.7ms)
```

which is a quite standard .js.erb file

```
    <% if  @group.errors.blank? -%> 
      $('#groupModal').modal('hide');
    <% else %>
      $( "#modalGroupAlert" ).removeClass('alert-info');
      $( "#modalGroupAlert" ).addClass('alert-danger');
      $( "#modalGroupAlert span" ).replaceWith( "<span><%= nicer_display_errors(@group.errors) %></span>" );
      $( "#modalGroupAlert" ).show();
    <% end %>
```

what's going on ? and why ? thanks for feedback

UPDATE 1 =======

As per Pavan comments, I updated my create code, and I also added the responders gem ( rails version 4.2.4 : Incompatibilities releases notes  - 3.2 respond_with / Class-Level respond_to )

> respond_with and the corresponding class-level respond_to have been moved to the responders gem. Add gem 'responders', '~> 2.0' to your Gemfile to use it:

my  :new and :create code are now

```
    def new
      @group = Group.new()
      authorize @group
      respond_with @group
    end

    def create
      @group =  Group.new(group_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        if @group.save #remove ? here
          format.html { redirect_to groups_path }
          format.js
        else 
          format.html { redirect_to new_group_path }
          format.js
        end
      end
    end
```

The :new.js is correctly handled

```
 Started GET "/groups/new.js?_=1446101853822" for ::1 at 2015-10-29 07:57:40 +0100
 Processing by GroupsController#new as JS
 ...
 Rendered groups/_new_modal_content.html.erb (15.8ms)
 Rendered groups/new.js.erb (23.6ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 84ms (Views: 65.7ms | ActiveRecord: 3.7ms)
```

But the :create is still raising the same error

```
 Started POST "/groups" for ::1 at 2015-10-29 07:57:48 +0100
 Processing by GroupsController#create as JS
 ...
 Rendered groups/create.js.erb (0.4ms)

 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 71ms (Views: 31.6ms | ActiveRecord: 21.2ms)
 AbstractController::DoubleRenderError - Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please...
```

Comment: Do you have a before_filter or after filter which may call render or redirect?

Comment: thanks Simon, I have before and after filters , but they don't impact the rendering... only authentication, variable setting and permissions

     before_filter :authenticate_user!
     before_action :set_group, except: [:index, :new, :create]

     after_filter :verify_authorized, :except => :index, unless: :devise_controller?
     after_filter :verify_policy_scoped, :only => :index

Comment: SORRY...  I'm wrong and you are right !!!
The Pundit after filters are the issues !!!   commenting them  make my code running !!  please add it as an answer so I can vote for it and maybe help debs running Pundit & Rails 4.2.4

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> AbstractController::DoubleRenderError - Render and/or redirect were
>   called multiple times in this action

You should change your `create` action to below

```
def create
  @group = Group.new(company_id: current_user.company_id, name: params[:name] )

  respond_to do |format|
    if @group.save #remove ? here
      format.html { redirect_to groups_path, notice: 'Group was successfully created.'}
      format.js
    else 
      format.html { redirect_to new_group_path }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Also as you are using ***Rails 4***, you should use ***strong parameters***.

```
private

def group_params
  params.require(:group).permit(:name).merge(company_id: current_user.comapany_id)
end
```

And change

```
@group = Group.new(company_id: current_user.company_id, name: params[:name] )
```

to

```
@group = Group.new(group_params)
```

Comment: Thanks Pavan... I updated the code as per your comments, but I'm still getting the same error..
As I am running Rails 4.2.4 , I also added the responders gem, to handle better the respond_with, respond_to, but  it doesn't change the behaviour....  rendering create.js.erb is raising the error...

Comment: @erwin Try removing  `respond_to :html, :js` from the controller.

Comment: found the issue :  see my answer to Simon's comment... the Pundit after_filter is guilty ...  commenting it make my code running...  so it's not treated with the responders....

Comment: @erwin Great! Please accept my answer if you found it helpful :)

Comment: I don't understand why this answer has been marked as accepted. It does not give a solution to the current issue.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments of the question, there is no problem with the code of the action.

However, one of the after_filter is making a call to render/redirect_to which leads to an `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError` error.

In the case of the author's problem, it seems it comes from the Pundit after_filters.

One possible solution is to use these filters as before_filters instead of after_filters. In fact, when a before_filter make a call to render or redirect_to, the action code is not executed and it is not possible to get the `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError` error.

Comment: to complete your answer ...  it's still possible to use the Pundit  after_filter with js responses :

       after_filter :verify_authorized

by skipping it in the format.js response block  :

       format.js { skip_authorization }

Comment: I had a similar case where and action created a parent then updated child records.  Authorisation was the culprit.